# GPS vs GNSS tags, do we need both?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

GPS technically only refers to the system established by the US, whereas GNSS is a general term including Beidou, Galileo, and GLONASS. (any others?).

Two questions use [gps](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps) and five questions use the more general [gnss](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss).

- https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps
- https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss

While GNSS is the more general term, many users may still search for a GPS tag because the term has been around so long it's used (incorrectly) interchangeably with GNSS in popular context.

I've made sure the two posts that have [gps](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps) also have [gnss](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss) so that they could be synonymized. That way when people type GPS they will see GNSS as the option.

I've made an edit to update the [gnss](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss) Wiki excerpt which is currently pending.

> Global Navigation Satellite System, including GPS, GLONASS, Galileo and BeiDou

**Question:** Would it make sense to use [gnss](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss) as the tag for all related questions, and convert GPS to a synonym? If so, what would be required?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. What should be done is to [merge the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) GPS to GNSS, so all GPS tags are changed by GPS. However, I would keep GPS as a tag synonym.

GPS have its own meaning but I think most questions are related to GNSS and not particularly to GPS. And as most people identifies any GNSS system as GPS I would leave it as a synonym. Other tags like Navstar can be crated to refer specifically to the US GNSS system.

As for the merge. It has to be done by a moderator, and I think there are several other merges that need to be made. Perhaps we can make a list of them so the moderators can do all in one go.

Comment: I've recently learned to go to meta and type "FAQ" in the search bar. It leads to all the goodies. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/303080 I'm not sure but what might be needed to do this is one or two more question that share both tags, I think with four or five, the process becomes easier?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the english word for what I try to explain, but this is a special case. At Europe, note I am not american, I truely didn't know what is GNSS until now. GPS is a ...(the word I don't find).... for every system that uses location via satellite, so it is what the posters, mosts of times, gonna tip for.  Sunday 14 when I tip GPS GNSS is not showed in the list. It should I agree with that.

Maybe the experts you know it is the acronym for american project, but you can always edit the post including GNSS if it is more accurated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for sharing your experience. I think then you agree that when people start typing GPS an option should appear immediately, because for some people GPS is the term they use for all GNSS. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh that feature would be sure usefull. Also it may works for earthquakes and seismology maybe